# How could I see crashes reports of older versions on ItunesConnect

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I released a version of a app in iTunesConnect, and now I wanna see the older crash reports.

Now the section `Manage Your Apps` contains only the newest version and I can't see crash of older versions.

Does somebody know how to find crashes of older versions?

Answer (score 5):

You can find it in Xcode->Window->Organizer->Crashes, click the app in left panel, in version and build menu, you can find crash reports for older version.

In iTunesConnect, you can only see the crash reports for current version.

references: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW1